# ANT - Find and replace string from bottom of file

Tags: regex, search, replace, ant

I am trying to use ant to replace the first occurrence of a regex from the bottom of a file.

I am presently using replaceregexp to search and replace, but can't find any way 
to make it work from the end of a file.

Does anyone have any suggestions to solve this?

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Comment: Isn't "first occurrence from the bottom of the file" just the same as last occurrence of the regex?

Answer (score 0):

Regex works from left to right (from top to bottom), but you can use a **negative lookahead** to assure that a match is the last one. The idea is that you only match something if the match isn't present afterwards.

If you want to match `word` (in any context, including `crossword`), `word(?![\s\S]*word)` will match only the last occurrence.